# Compatibility issues between `[utf8]{inputenc}` and certain macros of `tkz-base`

Tags: unicode, tkz-base

`\usepackage{tkz-base}` after `\usetikzlibrary{babel}` overcomes compatibility problems between `tkz-base` and `babel`, but if `[utf8]{inputenc}` is used `tikzpicture 1.` compiles OK, while `tikzpicture 2.`, unless commented out, causes the compilation to go into an endless loop.

```
\documentclass{article}
% RN. 4 Oct 2017
%=======================
\usepackage{comment}
%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek,russian,frenchb,english]{babel}
\usepackage{tkz-base}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
%
\begin{document}

1.\\
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\begin{scope}[rotate=30]
\tkzDefPoint(2,3){A}
\begin{scope}[shift=(A)]
\tkzDefPoint(90:5){B}
\tkzDefPoint(30:5){C}
\end{scope}
\end{scope}
\tkzDrawSegments[color=blue](A,B B,C C,A)
\tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C)
\tkzLabelPoints[above](B,C)
\tkzLabelPoints[below](A)
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{comment}
2.\\
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\tkzInit[xmax=6,ymax=6]
\tkzGrid
\tkzSetUpPoint[shape = circle,color = red,%
size = 8,fill = red!30]
\tkzDefPoint(-1+1,-1+4){O}
\tkzDefPoint({3*ln(exp(1))},{exp(1)}){A}
\tkzDefPoint({4*sin(FPpi/6)},{4*cos(FPpi/6)}){B}
\tkzDefPoint({4*sin(FPpi/3)},{4*cos(FPpi/3)}){B’}
\tkzDefPoint(30:5){C}
\tkzDefPoint[shift={(1,3)}](45:4){A’}
\begin{scope}[shift=(A)]
\tkzDefPoint(30:3){C’}
\end{scope}
\tkzDrawPoints[color=blue](O,B,C)
\tkzDrawPoints[color=red,%
shape=cross out](B’,A,A’,C’)
\tkzLabelPoints(A,O,B,B’,A’,C,C’)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{comment}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The problem comes from the curved apostrophes, you must replace them with straight apostrophes: \tkzDefPoint({4*sin(FPpi/3)},{4*cos(FPpi/3)}){B'}

Comment: @AndréC Do you want to write up an answer?

Comment: @TeXnician, All right, I'll write it down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem doesn't come from incompatibility between the `[utf8]{inputenc}` and `tkz-base` packages, but from `curved apostrophes` written instead of the `straights apostrophes`,you must replace them with straight apostrophes: `\tkzDefPoint({4*sin(FPpi/3)},{4*cos(FPpi/3)}){B'}`

This problem occurs most often when copying and pasting from the `tkz-euclide` manual. Here you have copied and pasted the code from page 21 of the manual (version 1.16 c).  This has written curved apostrophes: [Unicode Character' RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK' (U+2019)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2019/index.htm) instead of the straight  apostrophes [Unicode Character' APOSTROPHE' (U+0027)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0027/index.htm).

```
\documentclass{article}
% RN. 4 Oct 2017
%=======================
\usepackage{comment}
%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek,russian,frenchb,english]{babel}
\usepackage{tkz-base}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
%
\begin{document}

1.\\
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\begin{scope}[rotate=30]
\tkzDefPoint(2,3){A}
\begin{scope}[shift=(A)]
\tkzDefPoint(90:5){B}
\tkzDefPoint(30:5){C}
\end{scope}
\end{scope}
\tkzDrawSegments[color=blue](A,B B,C C,A)
\tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C)
\tkzLabelPoints[above](B,C)
\tkzLabelPoints[below](A)
\end{tikzpicture}

%\begin{comment}
2.\\
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\tkzInit[xmax=6,ymax=6]
\tkzGrid
\tkzSetUpPoint[shape = circle,color = red,%
size = 8,fill = red!30]
\tkzDefPoint(-1+1,-1+4){O}
\tkzDefPoint({3*ln(exp(1))},{exp(1)}){A}
\tkzDefPoint({4*sin(FPpi/6)},{4*cos(FPpi/6)}){B}
\tkzDefPoint({4*sin(FPpi/3)},{4*cos(FPpi/3)}){B'}
\tkzDefPoint(30:5){C}
\tkzDefPoint[shift={(1,3)}](45:4){A'}
\begin{scope}[shift=(A)]
\tkzDefPoint(30:3){C'}
\end{scope}
\tkzDrawPoints[color=blue](O,B,C)
\tkzDrawPoints[color=red,%
shape=cross out](B',A,A',C')
\tkzLabelPoints(A,O,B,B',A',C,C')
\end{tikzpicture}
%\end{comment}

\end{document}
```

Now the result is correct:

[image: ouput-quote]

Comment: I did indeed paste code from `Euclide` - my way of learning TikZ -, and your comment posted on 4 October was most helpful in fixing the problem. The kind of thing very difficult to identify without a hint. Well done!